# Kafka Consumer-java API running on local machine

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

Would like to execute the Kafka Consumer (Java code) in my local machine whereas my Kafka Producer and Kafka client is in another Hadoop cluster?

I am able to send message to kafka cluster using kafka producer script(kafka-console-producer.sh )but unable to access the message at kafka consumer in my local eclipse console ?

Please let me know if anything particular we need to change in the configuration side? appreicated for any example java code

Comment: Can you share consumer code to see what's wrong?

Comment: @Kaushal , i have posted the code below.

Comment: Try running consumer jar locally on your cluster

Comment: @Ketan... want to use my local machine as consumer...isn't that possible?

Comment: I can't comment on the possibilty of unning locally on eclipse, I also tried that, but was not able to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.hortonworks.example.kafka.consumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRebalanceListener;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import java.util.Collection;
Configuring Kafka for Kerberos
Over Ambari
May 9, 2016
9
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
public class BasicConsumerExample {
public static void main(String[] args) {`enter code here`
Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka.
example.com:6667");
// specify the protocol for SSL Encryption
consumerConfig.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,
"SASL_PLAINTEXT");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG,
"earliest");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
"org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.
apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
KafkaConsumer<byte[], byte[]> consumer = new
KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfig);
TestConsumerRebalanceListener rebalanceListener = new
TestConsumerRebalanceListener();
consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test-topic"),
rebalanceListener);
while (true) {
ConsumerRecords<byte[], byte[]> records = consumer.poll(1000);
for (ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record : records) {
System.out.printf("Received Message topic =%s, partition =%s,
offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.topic(), record.partition(),
record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
}
consumer.commitSync();
}
}
private static class TestConsumerRebalanceListener implements
ConsumerRebalanceListener {
@Override
public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
{
System.out.println("Called onPartitionsRevoked with partitions:" +
partitions);
}
@Override
public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)
{
System.out.println("Called onPartitionsAssigned with partitions:" +
partitions);
}
}
}
```